# how do I make calls to rest apis provided by a company

Tags: java, http, rest

I'd like to make calls to rest apis provided by [parse](https://www.parse.com/docs/rest) using java. 
Is there any api in java can do this? I'm totally new to this kind of
rest api call stuff.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, it is a simple URL that can be accessed through HTTP protocol. If so, you could use [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/) to handle this.

Comment: `RestTemplate` from Spring. Rest is done over HTTP, so you can also use any HTTP client.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2793150/1065197

Answer (score 1):

I have done well with Jersey: https://jersey.java.net

With Jersey you can create a server-side REST API as well a REST client, which is what you want. See the documentation at https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html

Comment: What I want to do is very easy. I know the url and it's a POST call. I also need to set some headers(The API key stuff) and some parameters for the POST call. Can you give me a hint what kind of api in Jersey is used to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Jersey is a good choice. It's an industry standard, the reference implementation and easy to use.

Here is a good tutorial with a simple helloworld example:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis It has a client part as well.  See section 5.5 in the linked document.

Comment: @MelanieMunden What I want to do is very easy. I know the url and it's a POST call. I also need to set some headers(The API key stuff) and some parameters for the POST call. Can you give me a hint what kind of api in Jersey is used to do this?

Comment: @herman What I want to do is very easy. I know the url and it's a POST call. I also need to set some headers(The API key stuff) and some parameters for the POST call. Can you give me a hint what kind of api in Jersey is used to do this?

Comment: @FihopZz I edited this answer to add info on doing a POST call and add headers (wait for the edit to be accepted).

Comment: @herman, where can I see your answer?

Comment: @FihopZz it didn't get accepted.  But look at the example in section 7.5 in the linked page.  It uses `WebResource.post(...)` to do the POST request.  Similarly, you can add headers using `WebResource.headers` (note: it's a fluent API)

Answer (score 0):

You can try RESTEasy as a rest client library: http://www.jboss.org/resteasy

Answer (score 0):

Spring has a great support for REST.It provides you the RestTemplate which avoids lot of boiler plate code when invoking a Rest API from the Client code.Below is an example

```
public class Client{
    RestTemplate restTemplate;
    public void callRestService() {
    ResponseObj obj = (ResponseObj) restTemplate.getForObject("rest url",ResponseObj.class,"urlVariables");  
}
```

}

Comment: Hi Anirudh. Thanks for your help. I have one more question for your code snippet. How can I add headers to the call?, I need to add API key and other stuff to make the call.

Comment: sorry for responding late on this.HttpEntity object which is passed as one of the parameters encapsulate the header information.Refer to spring API documentation about the HttpEntity object and how to set headers